# Blender VSE lags while editing video

Tags: eevee-render-engine, video-sequence-editor

My laptop is not the fastest one, and I created a blender project. There are a few stretched blocks. I unwrapped them and added a realistic texture.

I want to make a video with the length of 20-30 seconds. This video clip is decorated with a background music. But my problem is that I can't really edit the video, because the audio runs normal but the Video lags (~7fps).

I tried to look the preview only with materials or only with the objects. But nothing helped. I use Blender 2.8 alpha 2 (EEVEE).

In the later render everything is great but its a horror to edit. Any other ideas to show in the preview because even in wireframe mode it lags.

Comment: So no matter how you exported the frames whether as a video file or an image sequence I personally would edit the footage in Davinci Resolve, its free. It's probably run faster as well.

Comment: It is not clear what the issue is. Do you see the lag while playing the video in Blender VSE? if so you may just have to set the mode to AV Sync. If the problem is in the video files you produce then you need to tell us what settings you used and preferably try some other ones.

Comment: In the [timeline editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/timeline.html#synchronize-playback), you will find the playback settings, at the top of the menu change "No Sync" to "AV-sync".

Comment: The title of a question has a very clear, well defined purpose - to sum up the question. You should attempt to give your question an informative title, preferably in form of a question. The question is also not formed clearly. It is unclear what you are doing or trying to do. It is not clear what you mean by 'make a video', 'can't really edit the video', 'its a horror to edit' and how you can 'preview [a video] only with materials or only with the objects'. Please put some more effort into formulating your questions if you want to get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a problem in blender for quite a while. Definately not a 2.8 problem. Not quite the optimal solution but it works is to turn the video into an image sequence and then import it as an image sequence. I usually use ffmpeg to convert the video into an image sequence but I don't know how easy that is from a non unix pc. You can always just import it into blender and export it as an image sequence. I did recently see what I think is a big improvement in the 2.8 video editor where I think this problem is fixed allthough I can't conferm because it crashed 1 second later. 
A different problem which I don't think you are describing here would be just a framerate mismach so make sure your render settings fps is the same as that of your source video. 
(If the fps counter is red the problem is probably the first one I mentioned, could still be both though)